# spring jpa query SQLGrammarException on join @ManyToMany

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have `Way` POJO in my Spring Boot application, here is what it looks like:

```
public class Way {
    @Id
    private Long wayID;
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Relation> relations=new ArrayList<>();
```

Now I want to select all the ways that has relationID of a given value.
*`relationID` is a member of `Relation`* POJO.

So here is my query
**`@Query("select w from Way w join Relation relations where relations.relationID=?1")
    List<Way> selectAllWaysByRelationID(Long relationID);`**

But the error seems to be in my `JOIN` portion, it crashes and says:
**org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [select way0_.wayid as wayid1_5_ from way way0_ inner join relation relation1_ on where relation1_.relationid=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement**

How can I resolve this ?

I also tried this:

```
    @Query("select way from Way.relations full join Way.relations rel where rel.relationID=?1")
    List<Way> selectAllWaysByRelationID(Long relationID);
```

This too:

```
    @Query("select way from Way way join Way.relations rel where rel.relationID=?1")
    List<Way> selectAllWaysByRelationID(Long relationID);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `JOIN` you need to use alias of `Way` with `relations` field like this, `w.relations r` instead of `Way.relations`.

The complete query is below:

```
@Query("select w from Way w join w.relations r where r.relationID=?1")
List<Way> selectAllWaysByRelationID(Long relationID);
```